# SQL query is erroring in my framework but fine in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datamapper

This is strange as my query executes and returns the correct result in mysqlworkbench, however in my application I get a

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as category FROM products p ' at line 1

It's in codeignitor using datamapper.

```
$query="

SELECT CONCAT_WS('~', c3.name, c2.name, c1.name) as category 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN metadata m ON m.parent_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN category0_table c0 ON c0.id = m.value 
LEFT JOIN category1_table c1 ON c1.id = c0.parent_ID 
LEFT JOIN category2_table c2 ON c2.id = c1.parent_ID 
LEFT JOIN category3_table c3 ON c3.id = c2.parent_ID 
WHERE p.id =5 
AND m.key = 'my_category'";

$model = new Product_model();
$results = $model->query($query);
return $results;
```

I can't think what's wrong, I've tried taking out the concat statement.

Comment: are you sure it works on mysql since I can see an issue `m.key` `key` is a reserved keyword and you need to backtick it.

Comment: ahhhh let me try it!!!

Comment: no, it's still unhappy with same error message

Comment: can u add the code where you are adding the query ?

Comment: @Nicola  Abhik Chakraborty is right you need post your application level code as your query looks fine to me

Comment: but it's an sql syntax error I am getting

Comment: arghh you are right.... please delete this question someone, it's me being daft

Answer (score 0):

Why not use active record? It lets your application have the ability to be flexible on any platform running a multitude of different databases including (mysql, mssql, postgress, oracle). Just better practice imo. What if one day you want to run your application on a windows server? just install php in IIS and you're good to go. Or what if you are already on a Microsoft server running sql server with php in IIS and your IT dept needs to cut costs? You can say "hey I know a way we can cut thousands from the budget and not lose anything, just go open source!!" and then you get a promotion etc etc...you know the drill.

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT_WS('~',c3.name,c2.name,c1.name) as category")->
           from("products p")->
           join("metadata m','m.parent_id = p.id","left")->
           join("category0_table c0","c0.id=m.value","left")->
           join("category1_table c1","c1.id=c0.parent_ID","left")->
           join("category2_table c2","c2.id = c1.parent_ID","left")->
           join("category3_table c3","c3.id = c2.parent_ID","left")->
           where("p.id","5")
           where("m.key","my_category");

$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
    return $query->result();
}else {
    return FALSE;
}
```